# How can a key be renamed in an Association?

Tags: associations

Consider an example `Association`:

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "this_key_is_too_long_to_type" -> {1}|>;
```

Suppose I want to replace `"this_key_is_too_long_to_type"` with `"c"`. I can replace it by transforming into `Normal` land and back into `Association` land:

```
Association[
  ReplaceAll[Normal[assoc], Rule["this_key_is_too_long_to_type", rhs_] :> Rule["c", rhs]]]
```

But I have found with `Association`s that there is usually a compact and efficient way and that this double-transformation is usually a signal that I'm not using it. What's the best way to rename a key?

Comment: Based on the complexity of the answers, I'm going to wager that "... there is usually a compact and efficient way..." is false in this case.

Comment: @bobthechemist, if that's the case, let's use this as an opportunity to request `ReplaceKey` or something in a future version.

Comment: ...or at least a more general `KeyMapAt` or `AssociationMapAt`

Comment: What property does an Association have that implies that ReplaceAll cannot replace keys?  What is the general rule at play here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is, of course:

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "this_key_is_too_long_to_type" -> {1}|>;
assoc["c"] = assoc["this_key_is_too_long_to_type"];
assoc["this_key_is_too_long_to_type"] =.
assoc
(* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|> *)
```

Not sure if there's an elegant way to do it in one step.

Answer (score 19):

Somewhat similar to the answer of evanb, but without explicit mutations:

```
keyRename[a_, old_ -> new_] /; KeyExistsQ[a, old] := KeyDrop[old]@Append[a, new -> a[old]]
```

So that

```
keyRename[assoc, "this_key_is_too_long_to_type" -> "c"]

(* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|> *)
```

It should be noted that this solution doesn't preserve the order of the keys. A variant that does is:

```
keyRename[a_, key_ -> key_] := a
keyRename[a_, old_ -> new_] /; KeyExistsQ[a, old] := 
        KeyDrop[old]@Insert[asc, new -> asc[old], Key[old]]
```

Comment: Hi, Leonid. Your method seems only works for one key. What if I have a bunch to replace. I can't understand why association can not use simply `/.` For example, `assoc/.{c1->d1,c2->d2,...}` to replace many keys in a single step. I encountered this kind of occasion many times, quite annoying.

Comment: @matheorem I think that massive key renaming is not such a common (frequently needed) operation. Using `ReplaceAll` will be ambiguous - do you want to replace keys or values. Since `KeyDrop` and `Append` are constant-time for associations, you can in principle use my `keyRename` with `Fold`: `Fold[keyRename, assoc, replacements]`. Or, if speed is important,  do something more clever, all at once, that would be a few times faster.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, even shorter, along the lines of ArgentoSapiens's O(n): keyReplace[rule_] := KeyMap[Replace[rule]]; keyReplace[{rules__}] := KeyMap[Replace[{rules}]]; /// you'd be surprised how often it's necessary to replace keys programmatically - namespace normalization from multiple sources.

Comment: This will modify the order of the keys though. I cannot come up with a solution that is not O(n) and it truly will not change anything else in the association than the key name. Of course, one has to consider the case when the renaming will cause a key collision. Still, it seems like there should be a simple solution ...

Comment: Maybe `keyRename[asc_?AssociationQ, old_ -> new_] := KeyDrop[old]@Insert[asc, new -> asc[old], Key[old]]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs That should work, except you'd have to throw in a check that `old` and `new` are different, and have a no-op otherwise (your suggestion would in this case remove the key). Could just add a separate clause like `keyRename[asc_?AssociationQ, key_ -> key_] := asc`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Feel free to edit your solution into the post.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I have added to your code a clause for trivial renaming case, otherwise for that case the function would still have a bug.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to do it in one line without using `Normal` first.

```
KeyMap[If[SameQ[#, "this_key_is_too_long_to_type"], "c", #] &, assoc]
```

Or:

```
KeyMap[# /. "this_key_is_too_long_to_type" -> "c" &, assoc]
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of keys, while it should better be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

I normally use the operator

```
KeyMap[Replace["this_key_is_too_long_to_type" -> "c"]]
```

and apply it to the association. It generalizes easily to renaming multiple keys:

```
KeyMap[Replace[{"a" -> "x", "b" -> "y"}]]
```

This is simple and convenient, but it will have to check every key, which is not optimal if you only want to rename one. In that case, use [Leonid's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64804/12).

Answer (score 2):

Late in the game. Here is a generalization of @ArgentoSapiens, encapsulated in a function and working for lists of Associations.

```
keyRename // ClearAll
keyRename[a:{_Association...}, rule_Rule]:= keyRename[a, {rule}]
keyRename[a_Association, rule_Rule]:= keyRename[a, {rule}]
keyRename[a_Association, rule:{_Rule...}]:= KeyMap[#/.rule &, a]
keyRename[a:{_Association...}, rule:{_Rule...}]:= keyRename[#,rule]&/@a
```

Some tests:

```
a = {<|"a"-> 1, "b"-> 2|>, <|"a"-> 3, "b"-> 4|>};
keyRename[a,{"a" -> "a2", "b" -> "b2"}]
keyRename[a,"a" -> "a2"]
keyRename[a[[1]],"a"-> "a2"]
```

we get

```
{<|"a2" -> 1, "b2" -> 2|>, <|"a2" -> 3, "b2" -> 4|>}
{<|"a2" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a2" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>}
<|"a2" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
```