# Different Set Semantics - Why is assoc["a"] =. different from assoc[["a"]] =.?

Tags: associations, language-design

Accessing parts of an `Association` can be done either using `Part` or the `[]` extraction notation. Although similar, there are subtle differences and I'm wondering if (immutable) key removal is part of that subtlety or set to be updated. For example, *changing* a key value is similar

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>;
assoc["a"] = 0;
assoc

(* <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 2|> *)
```

since analogously

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>;
assoc[["a"]] = 0;
assoc

(* <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 2|> *)
```

but *removing* a key-value is apparently not since while

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>;
assoc["a"] =.;
assoc

(* <|"b" -> 2|> *)
```

analogously

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, b -> 2|>;
assoc[["a"]] =.;
assoc

(* Unset::write: Tag Part in <|a->1,b->2|>[[a]] is Protected. >>
  $Failed
  <|"a" -> 1, b -> 2|>
 *)
```

Comment: I can see how this `Unset` behaviour might be different for `Association` compared with a `List` given the former is a "symbolically indexed list" with a different notion of mutability (n.b. removing a list element in this way also fails since no particular symbol is being unset) but I also tend to think that it is perhaps natural to expect similar behaviour.

Comment: I am actually surprised that `Unset` works for the `[ ]` syntax for assocs - I wasn't aware of that. While I can understand that it has some syntactical nicety, I don't feel that this sits well with the standard sematnics of `Unset`, which previously was used strictly for global rules. This looks like a case where syntax wins over semantics, and a rather questionable design decision, in my view.

Comment: Awareness can be a funny thing as I myself actually first noticed this comparing one of [your answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64804/2249) that itself compared itself with a previous answer that did just this.

Comment: You are totally right. Somehow I wasn't surprised at that point, while I should've been. Actually, with `Unset`, this isn't clear-cut case to me. We may try to think of an `Unset` as of reverse to `Set` or `SetDelayed`. Now, `Set` serves two purposes: 1. create global rules (like SetDelayed, but immediate), and 2. Efficient in-place modifications of parts of expressions stored in symbols, when used with `Part`. The first use in general and conceptual. The second use is special, and comparatively low-level. I think it is rather unfortunate that the same operator (`Set`) is used in both cases...

Comment: Here is what I would consider a cleaner design, in terms of semantics: `Set` would *only* create rules, while there would be a separate `SetPart` for in-place part modifications. Now, `Unset` would be exact opposite of `Set`, that is, used *only* to destroy global rules.  Now, if we think about it, using `Unset` on a part makes no sense. You can either delete a part, or modify it, but not unset. So, logically, we'd need a `DeletePartFrom` operation, which actually exists for assocs (`KeyDropFrom`). But, such operation can't be general, because general expressions are based on sequences, and ..

Comment: ... there isn't a cheap way to remove element from or add to a sequence - which is different for keys in assocs, where it *is* possible to do that cheaply. So, there seems to be no general need for `DeletePartFrom`, from the performance viewpoint, so it may only be useful as a conceptual generalization, or may be for nested mixed structures involving lists and assocs. In any case, using `Unset` for such purposes doesn't strike me as a logical thing to do - we don't really unset anything, but rather delete a part (or, here, key-value pair). I think,  `Unset` in this context is  confusing.

Comment: Yes, I agree that boiled to its essence is deciding to what extent an act of creation should be distinguished from an act of modification but irrespective, it seems more coherent to consistently allow `Unset`  whenever `Set` is allowed. I'm not sure however, that `Set` "shouldn't" be used for both; `UnSet`/`Set` can also be viewed as modifying the rule-space but these almost philosophical positions aside, I place equal emphasis on the "syntax side" or at least consider it an integral part of WL's pedagogy/learning curve. *If* one grants that in-place modification is needed, that it should ..

Comment: ... include an infix form and be natural (all of which I do) then I see no other alternative but to use "=" . Maybe there could be another "=" symbol or instead have it parsed to `SetPart`, or perhaps `SetAt` for non-symbol arguments but both seem to add unnecessary complexity without an overwhelming gain in language purity.

Comment: The problem, as I explained, is that `Set` used for part modifications of existing expressions does not create anything new, and therefore the semantics of `Unset` in this case is generally undefined. `Set` used to create can be matched by `Unset`, while `Set` used to modify can't. This is as simple as that, and so I disagree with *"it seems more coherent to consistently allow `Unset` whenever `Set` is allowed"* - and this is why I was talking about `SetPart`. But we start running in circles, so I better stop at this point :)

Comment: `Set` however, *can* also be used for part creations which is why I don't agree that the "semantics of `Unset` is generally undefined". The coherency stems from  `Unset` undoing what a  `Set` does either in symbol/rule or part creation - (that `Set` can also be used to modify symbols/parts doesn't affect this inverse relationship instead being a byproduct of a natural setting/modifying nexus). But yes easy to get into loops here and I might self-answer later to try and save this question from too much triviality :)

Comment: How do you create new parts with `Set`? I am very curious. Note that  in my book part modifications which replace some part with a different expression don't count as new part creation. Also global uses of `Set` used like `lst = Append[lst, elem] ` don't count, since this is not a part assignment, but a modification of an entire global rule.

Comment: `assoc = <|a -> 1|>; assoc[b] = 2; assoc` giving `<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>` with this and other semantics being extended to `Lists`, `Dataset`s and `[[]]` to reach said generality. Longer explanation given in self-answer.

Comment: Well, ok. I am not a big fan of this design, but it is obviously convenient for the end-user and this indeed justifies  `Unset` working with the similar syntax.

Comment: Yes history has a narky habit of getting in the way but (having not noticed that overloading of `Set` before)  `@=` at least offers a way towards a subsequent separation ... of sorts.

Answer (score 4):

While perhaps appearing as peripheral language design issue, I think clarifying the varieties of in-place, L-assignment further illuminates the much more consequential notion of mutability/immutability within the WL.

My conclusion is that yes the difference noted between `[]` and `[[]]` assignments (both in `Unset` and more generally) is somewhat incoherent with the current `[]` implementation representing the most consistent, in-place interpretation. Accordingly, extending this interpretation to all other varieties would add coherency (A "bug" label where in-place assignment *doesn't* align with `[]`'s idiom however, doesn't seem warranted so I'll instead label such deviations, a "mite").

Let's start with `List`s by way of background:

```
    ls = {a, b, c};
    ls[[2]] = B;
    ls
 (*
    {a, B, c}
 *)
```

As pointed out by Leonid Shifron in the question comments, `Set` is being used in two subtly different ways here; in the first instance a variable is being *created*; in the second instance a *part* is being *modified*. While not keeping these usages separate lies behind subsequent differences (in this periphery at least), IMO an overriding imperative here is pedagogy; the use of `Set` and its infix form `"="` is so ingrained, its application so universal, that the described dual usage is both natural and an integral part of *Mathematica*'s learning curve. Further, existing coherency levels bear enhancement as to be outlined.

Firstly note that the creative usage of `Set` affects WL's evaluation sequence in addition to (or as part of) defining a new structure:

```
    << GeneralUtilities` (* needed for Definitions *)
    Definition@ls
    Definitions@ls
(*
    ls = {a, B, c} 
    {HoldPattern[ls] :> {a, B, c}}
*)
```

but as `Set` giveth, `Unset` taketh

```
    ls =.
    Definition@ls
    Definitions@ls
(*
    Null 
    {}
*)
```

This `Unset`usage at a global or "whole structure" level can be viewed as both undoing `Set`'s actions or else removing a structure. In the latter case, given `Set`'s dual usage, coherency posits that a similar part removal should also be available - in other words can one taketh away part of a structure using this syntax? Alas and unfortunately, for `List`'s the answer is no (although the situation is different with `Associations` as we will soon see)

```
    ls = {a, b, c}
    ls[[2]] =.
    ls
(*
    {a, b, c} 
    Unset::write: Tag Part in {a,b,c}[[2]] is Protected. >>
    $Failed
    {a, b, c}
*)
```

but I regard this as another "mite". I maintain that it is perfectly reasonable and natural to expect that instead `{a,c}` be returned given `ls[[2]]=.`'s  removal semantics. Conceptually I don't see too great a distance between removing a whole structure from a namespace and removing a part (while recognizing that the former is also accompanied with the removal of a rule). We can view these operations through the lens of a *coherency matrix* where we observe that the outstanding action not yet considered is the *creative* action of `Set` on *parts* (an implementation of which ensures that `UnSet` consistently undo's `Set`'s actions).

[image]

This suggests that

```
    ls = {a, b, c}
    ls[[4]] = d;
    ls
(*         
    Set::partw: Part 4 of {a,b,c} does not exist. >>
    {a, b, c}
*)
```

could instead return `{a,b,c,d}` (which, that it doesn't, I regard as another "mite").

When it comes to `Association`s however, all the coherency just described *is* nicely implemented as we can observe by stepping through each cell in the *coherency matrix*.

[image]

IMO, a gain in coherency would result from squishing all outstanding mites by extending `[]`'s `Set` semantics to `ls[[]]`, `assoc[[]]` and `dataset[]`.

Note that in relation to creative part applications of `Set`, previous examples relied on the part extending the structure "continuously". Discontinuous part creations require the insertion of missing elements semantics for which are already provided by `Missing[]` and `SparseArrays`. For example,

```
  ls = {a, b, c};
  ls[[5]] = e;
  ls
(*
  {a, b, c, Missing[], e}
*)
```

Currently, this insertion does not occur even for `assoc[]` since while

```
    assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> <|4 -> c|>|>;
    assoc[3, 5] = d
    assoc
 (*
    d
    <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> <|4 -> c, 5 -> d|>|> 
 *)
```

we have that

```
   assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> <|4 -> c|>|>;
   assoc[3, 5, 2] = d;
   assoc

(* Set::kval: The value for the key 5 does not exist. >>
   <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> <|4 -> c|>|>
 *)
```

We return to the connection between immutability and mutability. This exposition and suggested unification of `Set`'s semantics, is by no means intended to emphasise or promote it as the dominant or even preferred method for the frequent changing of data structures. `Set` is ideal for beginners, for initiating structures, for changing single elements in the simple immutable fashion and finally for recording chains of changes. There are, of course, more flexible functions for handling richer mutations. For example, `Set` can't readily handle changes that involve a function of the part's value as provided by `MapAt`.

```
    assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c|>;
    MapAt[Capitalize@ToString@# &, assoc, 2]
(*
    <|1 -> a, 2 -> "B", 3 -> c|>
*)
```

nor can it, for example, singly handle multiple modifications in the manner of `ReplacePart`

```
    assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c|>;
    ReplacePart[assoc, {1 -> "A", 3 -> "C"}]
(*
    <|1 -> "A", 2 -> b, 3 -> "C"|>
*)
```

Finally, `Set` doesn't enjoy the ready compositions via operator forms within a `Query`

```
    assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c|>;
    Query[MapAt[Capitalize@ToString@# &, 2]@*ReplacePart[{1 -> "A", 3 -> "C"}]]@assoc
(* 
    <|1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"|>
*)
```

Not only are these richer modifications but they are also done so *mutably* with the base definition of `assoc` remaining unaffected. This is a powerful and important feature of the WL that is, IMO, essential to encouraging and facilitating seamless experimentation. In fact, as touched on [elsewhere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61839/2249) the interplay between mutable/immutable structures captures  scientific practice and even the unfolding of evolution. More locally, much of *Mathematica*'s prototyping ability IMO stems from WL's mutable nature but structures eventually need augmentation to record finds, a fact that I think explains recurring questions on immutable modifications. Currently, a whole/global `Set` is required

```
  assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c|>;
  assoc = Query[MapAt[Capitalize@ToString@# &, 2]@*ReplacePart[{1 -> "A", 3 -> "C"}]]@assoc
(*
   <|1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C"|>
*)
```

Eventually repeated application of this construction starts to invoke "boilerplateness". For some users it may also be a little disconcerting minimally changing a large legacy data structure by apparently, expensively copying the entire structure (a misconception not perhaps easily disabused for those less versed in mutable/immutable distinctions). But is there a more natural, infix approach to immutable assignment? I think so. We can take our cue from `AddTo` or `TimesBy`, `a+=1` or `b*=2` whereby the content immediately wrapping the `=` defines an operator set to operate on the data structure defined by the first symbol.

IMO, the relevant, "infix operator" begging for a call to action here is "`@=`"; behold the "naturalness" of the following:

```
assoc @= MapAt[Capitalize@ToString@# &, 2];
assoc @= ReplacePart[2 -> B];
assoc @= ReplacePart[{1 -> "A", 3 -> "C"}];
assoc @= Query[MapAt[Capitalize@ToString@# &, 2]@* ReplacePart[{1 -> "A", 3 -> "C"}]];
```

Its generality can be seen how existing idioms get covered

```
a += 1;
a @= # + 1 &
```

or in an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54491/2249) to dataset in-place assignment

```
dataset[Select[#age > 30 &], "salary"] *= 2
dataset @= Query[All, MapAt[If[#age > 30, 2#&, Identity], #, "salary"] &]
```

or by "rendering redundant" existing immutable variants such as `AppendTo`,`PrependTo`, `KeyDropFrom` (while reducing the need for future variants )

```
assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c|>;

assoc @= Append[4 -> d];
assoc @= KeyDrop[2]
```

This is yet another example of the power of [operator forms.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/v10s-operator-forms-what-are-they-good-for) Note that in these immutable versions there is usually a sense of one large, legacy structure, being augmented by adding/changing a single element. Hence operator forms, which require a natural target structure to operate on, naturally emerge by considering the original structure as constituting such a target. Other functions, such as `Join`, on the other hand, have traditionally considered joinable elements to have equal prominence so that without an obvious target no such operator form emerges.  The notion of an immutable, infix assignment alters this whereby the following becomes more natural:

```
assoc = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c|>;
assoc @= Join[<|4 -> d|>];
```

We can see how common immutable, infix assignment improves code readability and data structure tracking

```
capitalizeMiddle = MapAt[Capitalize@ToString@# &, 2];
replaceBookends = ReplacePart[{1 -> "A", 3 -> "C"}];
logicallyExtend = Join[<|4 -> d, 5 -> e|>]; (* no current operator form *)
capIt = Prepend[0 -> z];
drop3 = KeyDrop@3;
addSuffix = StringJoin["Suffix"]  (* no current operator form *)

assoc @= capitalizeMiddle;
assoc @= replaceBookends;
assoc @= Query[capitalizeMiddle@*replaceBookends];
assoc @= logicallyExtend;
assoc @= capIt;
assoc @= drop3;
st @= addSuffix;
```

Currently there does not exist such an infix operator, `@=`, and while it could be introduced by the `Notation` utility, general package development [doesn't gel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/is-package-development-via-initializationcells-compatible-with-creating-new-no) with such integration; we can however, currently implement it by instead borrowing an existing, if mildly related, infix operator, `\[DotEqual]`

```
 SetAttributes[DotEqual, HoldFirst];
 DotEqual[a_, b_] := a = b@a; 

     assoc = < 1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c|>;
     j = 4;
     {
       assoc \[DotEqual] capitalizeMiddle,
       assoc \[DotEqual] capIt,
       assoc \[DotEqual] drop3,
       j \[DotEqual] (2#&)
      };
     {assoc, j}
(*
     {<|0 -> z, 1 -> a, 2 -> "B"|>, 8}
*)
```

whose visual sense is better provided by an actual visual

[image]

For `Join`/`StringJoin`, operator forms need defining (since as mentioned, in this idiom's absence, no target operand presents) and not wanting to tinker with core, native definitions we can instead create `o` operator forms when these are not built-in

```
oJoin[h_] := Function[{expr}, Join[expr, h], HoldAll];
oStringJoin[h_] := Function[expr, StringJoin[expr, h], HoldAll];

logicallyExtend = oJoin[<|4 -> d, 5 -> e|>];
addSuffix = oStringJoin@"Suffix";

    z = {1}; st = "stem";
    z \[DotEqual] logicallyExtend;
    st \[DotEqual] addSuffix;
    {z, st}
(* 
    {<|0 -> z, 1 -> a, 2 -> "B"|>, 8}
*)
```

Again visually

[image]

`Set` naturally sets things off in mutable, experimental playgrounds; it then helps record interesting finds, something more naturally done with immutable, infix assignment.