# Rename Keys in Nested Association

Tags: replacement, associations

I am looking to expand this post, [How can a key be renamed in an Association?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64795/how-can-a-key-be-renamed-in-an-association).

I would like a function that automatically replaces any and all keys with the rule.

Here is what I have so far

```
KeyReplace[data_, rule_] := KeyMap[Replace[#, rule] &, data];
KeyReplace[data_, {rules__}] := KeyMap[Replace[#, {rules}] &, data];
KeyReplace[data_List, rule_] := KeyReplace[#, rule] & /@ data;
KeyReplace[data_List, {rules__}] := KeyReplace[#, {rules}] & /@ data;
KeyReplace[data_Association, rule_, depth_: 1] := MapAt[KeyReplace[#, rule] &, data, {depth, All}];
KeyReplace[data_Association, {rules__}, depth_: 1] := MapAll[KeyReplace[#, rules] &, data, {depth, All}];

test=<|"key1" -> <|"val11" -> val11, "val12" -> val12|>, "key2" -> {<|"val21" -> val21, "val22" -> val22|>, <|"val31" -> val31, "val32" -> val32|>}|>;
```

This works for the everything except the "val11" and "val12" keys.

The function should just take in any data structure and then replace the keys that match the pattern.

```
KeyReplace[test,"vall11"-> "new"]
(*<|"key1" -> <|"new" -> val11, "val12" -> val12|>, "key2" -> {<|"test" -> val21, "val22" -> val22|>, <|"val31" -> val31, "val32" -> val32|>}|>*)

KeyReplace[test,{"vall11"-> "new","val32"-> "new2"}]
(*<|"key1" -> <|"new" -> val11, "val12" -> val12|>, "key2" -> {<|"test" -> val21, "val22" -> val22|>, <|"val31" -> val31, "new2" -> val32|>}|>*)

KeyReplace[test,"val32"-> "new2"]
(*<|"key1" -> <|"vall11" -> val11, "val12" -> val12|>, "key2" -> {<|"test" -> val21, "val22" -> val22|>, <|"val31" -> val31, "new2" -> val32|>}|>*)
```

This is as close as I could get but could not get the first association to replace keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
keyReplace[assoc_?AssociationQ, rules_] :=
 MapAt[
  KeyMap[Replace[rules]],
  assoc,
  Position[assoc, _?AssociationQ]
];
```

Try it out:

```
assoc = AssociationThread[
  Range[6],
  {
   <|"a" -> 1, 3 -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|4 -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>
  }
];
keyReplace[assoc, i_Integer :> i + 1]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew there was a better way.  Now only define it once instead of 6 times.